# go structure filling: pointer receiver vs returned values

Tags: go, code-readability

Looking for a reference to a good reading or sharing an experience of what is better from the code readability/maintenance/best-practice perspective.

There are two options on how to assign values to struct fields:

- call a function/method that returns values and do an explicit assignment in the main code
- use a pointer receiver method and fill the struct inside the method.

I'm not really concerned about the code productivity here, but more about code readability and maintenance in the future. The first method makes the main code more cluttered but allows to see which fields are filled from the one place. While the second one makes the main code cleaner while requiring to jump into methods and look there which exact fields are filled out. I wonder about the pros and cons of each approach and if are there any other ways to solve the readability problem.

#### Option 1 - detailed main code

```
type Customer struct {
    ID           int
    FName        string
    LName        string
    DOB          string
    SacredNumber string
    NotYet       string
}

func (c *Customer) fillMyCustomerGeneralWReturn() (fname, lname, dob string) {
    fname = getFNameByID(c.ID)
    lname = getLNameByID(c.ID)
    dob = getDOBByID(c.ID)
    return fname, lname, dob
}

func (c *Customer) fillMyCustomerSacredInfoWReturn() string {
    return getSacredNumberByIDFromVenus(c.ID)
}

func main() {

    cust := Customer{ID: 5}
    cust.FName, cust.LName, cust.DOB = cust.fillMyCustomerGeneralWReturn()
    cust.SacredNumber = cust.fillMyCustomerSacredInfoWReturn()
}
```

#### Option 2 - cleaner main code, but less visibility

```
type Customer struct {
    ID           int
    FName        string
    LName        string
    DOB          string
    SacredNumber string
    NotYet       string
}

func (c *Customer) fillMyCustomerGeneral() {
    c.FName = getFNameByID(c.ID)
    c.LName = getLNameByID(c.ID)
    c.DOB = getDOBByID(c.ID)
}

func (c *Customer) fillMyCustomerSacredInfo() {
    c.SacredNumber = getSacredNumberByIDFromVenus(c.ID)
}

func main() {

    cust := Customer{ID: 5}
    cust.fillMyCustomerGeneral()
    cust.fillMyCustomerSacredInfo()
}
```

Comment: IMHO you should use a different object to fill it. Call it `CustomerRepository` with a method `Find(*Customer)` or `FindByID(int) *Customer`

Comment: The second option is more GoLang style. Indeed the WithOption() is frequently used to fill fields.  It is similar to the second one above. And it is more elegant and encapsulating and it can even be used to hide some fields.

Comment: I believe there is a separation of concerns issue here. The method that gets the values that need to go into the fields should not be a method of `Customer` but of some `CustomerStore` or something. Similar to the suggestion by Tiago: `customerStore.FindByID(id int) *Customer` would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I suppose it should be something like this:

```
type Customer struct {
    ID           int
    FName        string
    LName        string
    DOB          string
    SacredNumber string
    NotYet       string
}

type CustomerRepository struct {
}

func (*CustomerRepository) FindByID(c int) *Customer {
    var returnCustomer Customer
    returnCustomer.ID = c
    returnCustomer.FName = getFNameByID(c)
    returnCustomer.LName = getLNameByID(c)
    returnCustomer.DOB = getDOBByID(c)
    return &returnCustomer
}

func (*CustomerRepository) SetSacredNumber(c *Customer) {
    c.SacredNumber = getSacredNumberByIDFromVenus(c.ID)
    return
}

func main() {

    var customerRepo CustomerRepository
    cust := customerRepo.FindByID(5)
    customerRepo.SetSacredNumber(cust)
    fmt.Println(*cust)
}
```